# How to Kill Terminal in VSCode using a python code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I understand that using `import os os._exit(0)` will pause the code, but I would like to **kill terminal** completely, as if I were clicking on the button shaped like a trash can.

Is there any way to do this so I can put it inside my python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hacky and won't work inside a Python subprocess, but it works in a basic sense:

```
import os
ppid = os.getppid()
os.system("taskkill /f /pid " + str(ppid))
```

Answer (score 1):

*# This is another way of doing it more pythonic way. Step 1: import os and signal. Step 2: call os.kill with parameters parent process id and SIGTERM (i.e. Signal to terminate the process)*

```
import os
import signal
os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```